# Why use “un jour” in the 1st sentence and “une journée” in the 2nd?

Tags: usage, indications-de-temps

> 1 : Repousse ton voyage, ne serait-ce que d’**un jour** !
>
> {au lieu de} : Repousse ton voyage, ne serait-ce que d’**une journée** !
>
> 2 : Que la vie subsiste, ne serait-ce qu’**une journée** de plus.
>
> {au lieu de} : Que la vie subsiste, ne serait-ce qu’**un jour** de plus.

In most cases, I’m familiar with the difference of usage between “un jour” and “une journée”, but not in this particular instance.

Comment: Where are the sentences from? *Repoussez ton voyage* is not correct.

Comment: It should be *Repousse ton voyage* or *Repoussez votre voyage*, not a mixture of both.

Comment: Where is the second one from? *Une journée* is slightly unusual, but there might be an explication to be found in the context.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez Hi. For the 1st sentence, I guess it's true, after all, when they say that you can't edit your own writing! Merci. I vaguely recall that the 2nd sentence was used in a subtitle of something in the context: "one more **(entire)** day would make a huge difference", as opposed to simply saying "one more day".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you're counting days purely as a countdown or a duration, without caring about what you do during them, it's always "*jour*". You say "*dans trois jours*", but never "*dans trois journées*". So when you're in a idea of counting days but it happens to be one (like counting by how many days you'll postpone something), use "*jour*"

When you use "*journée*", even in plural (you can!), you're often highlighting what you do during them : "*il passe ses journées à rien faire*". So it makes sense, when talking about living the present day, to use "*journée*" instead of "*jour*". (Notice you're not counting them precisely)

However, in the second example, it's not mandatory to use "*journée*", "*jour*" would have worked fine, you're also kind of counting days.

There are some cases where the two are interchangeable, sometimes it sounds more poetic to use one or the other.

Comment: Merci. So the idea of "activities" is the key when you use "journée". :) Now that I think on it, in the following instance, there is indeed a connotation of "activities": "J'ai eu mon lot d'aventures pour la journée. {PAS: jour}" = "I've had my share of adventures for the day ('s activities)".

Answer (score 1):

- jour is basically a unit of time, 24h.
- journée is the period from sunrise to sunset

so basically, if you stay "one more day", you can use both of them. The idea is that you have to enjoy your stay so during the day, you will generally not enjoy your night (but you can too of course).

Both sentences have the same meaning here.